# ts(2339) while fetching data from API (React/TS)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, api, react-hooks

I am trying to fetch data from an endpoint in which the data is structured as:

```
Object {
  Names[objects]
}
```

but when trying to access valid properties on the response data, they do not show. Specifically, I am given `Property 'names' does not exist on type 'any[]'`. Here is my custom fetch hook (I've simplified it a bit for the sake of this post):

```
const useFetch = (url: string) => {
  const [fetchError, setFetchError] = useState(null);
  const [loadingStatus, setLoadingStatus] = useState('waiting for request');
  const [resData, setResData] = useState([] as any[]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!url) return;
    setLoadingStatus(`fetching data from ${url}`);
    axios.get(url)
      .then(response => {
        setResData(response.data);
        setLoadingStatus('Data fetched successfully');
      })
      .catch(error => {
        setFetchError(error);
        setLoadingStatus('Error occurred fetching');
      });
  }, [url]);
  
  return {loadingStatus, resData, fetchError}
}

export { useFetch };
```

and in `App.tsx`:

```
const App: React.FC = () => {
  const { resData, loadingStatus, fetchError } = useFetch(url);

  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <h1>Fetched data</h1>
      <div>Fetch status: {loadingStatus}</div>
      <div>{resData?.names}</div> // ts(2339) right here
    </div>
  );
}
```

I have searched other resources trying to solve this issue but I am scratching my head. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You've defined `resData` as an array so the error message is correct; arrays don't have `names` properties

Comment: Did you reduce this code as [mcve], or did you just remove parts that seemed irrelevant? Because there's nothing in your code that references `.students` so while an error is fully expected, given the code you're showing it wouldn't be _that_ error.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans That was a typo; I changed it to reflect it as this was intended to be a minimal example.

Comment: Remember to show the _actual_ error(s) you get. Ideally, your MCVE does not change the error, because otherwise you're asking about a different problem. But if you do post code that has a technically different error, run your code, capture the new error, and then talk about _that_ error in your post.

Comment: @Phil sorry, that was a typo as I meant to reflect that in my example. 'names' is just the name of the array within the response object. I'm a bit confused on how it should be typed then, as every other type I have tried does not seem to change the root issue.

Comment: You're really missing out by not typing your state properties. I always feel like if you've got `any` in a Typescript project, you can do better

Comment: Look at how you initialise (and by virtue of the value, _typed_) your `resData` value... `[] as any[]`. It's an array. If I had `let foo = [1,2,3]` would you expect `foo.names` to be defined?

Comment: @Phil is the type not inferred by the initial state, though? None of my state properties are of type any.  I see your point; typing it as an object doesn't seem to change the error. I appreciate your time, though.  Thanks! Edit: nevermind, fixed it.

Comment: That's what I'm saying. Your initial state is an array so therefore the type of `resData` is an array

Comment: The issue I'm having now is that if I change resData?.names to something like resData?.names.first to access the first name property without refreshing, it works fine. However, the next time I reload the page I get an error indicating that names is undefined

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the type of your response data and therefore `resData` looks like this...

```ts
interface Name {
  first: string;
  last: string;
  // and anything else
}

interface ResData {
  names: Name[];
}
```

You should properly type both your state and the Axios response

```ts
// Define your initial value or omit it
const [resData, setResData] = useState<ResData>({
  names: []
});
const [fetchError, setFetchError] = useState<AxiosError>();
const [loadingStatus, setLoadingStatus] = useState<string>("waiting for request");

useEffect(() => {
  if (!url) return;
  setLoadingStatus(`fetching data from ${url}`);
  axios.get<ResData>(url) // define the response type here
    .then(response => {
      setResData(response.data);
      setLoadingStatus('Data fetched successfully');
    })
    .catch(error => {
      setFetchError(error);
      setLoadingStatus('Error occurred fetching');
    });
}, [url]);
```

The above defines the initial `resData` value with an empty `names` array but you could also leave it undefined...

```ts
const [resData, setResData] = useState<ResData>();
```

but then you'd need checks for nullish values.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense.  Thank you for your time!